# When to create another package in Java/Android

Tags: java, android

Under what conditions should you define a new package within java?

I'm interested in responses for an Android app and a simple web application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of a package in Java or a namespace in C++ or a module in Python, is to keep related code together to promote modularization and to keep class names from clashing with other projects or libraries.

You don't have to create separate packages. I would take a look at a few open source Java projects to see how they manage their package layouts. Keep in mind that it can be taken too far as well.

Answer (score 2):

When you need to create a logical separation between classes.

Answer (score 2):

A good general rule is to put code in another package when there is several classes making up some functionality that would be reusable on its own when taken out of context of the app its being created for.

Things like a single class to change part of an image, just leave it as a single class in the project, and copy it around or post it to a blog eet...

Things like 6-7 class files that create, maintain and manage something like downloading several images from the web for different resolutions and serving the app up the right image it needs when it needs it, while handling network connections and things. This would be a good example of something to split out into a separate package. The code is highly reusable, not too specific for a single app, and it is easy to define a separation where the package could be used on its own without the original app.

Answer (score 1):

Just like folders, how you manage folders is the way how you manage packages.

Group something similar:

```
- background                // Package
   - xml                   // Package
       - xmlHandler.java
       - xml2Handler.java
       - xml3Handler.java
   - server                // Package
       - serverUrl.java
       - serverUtil.java
- ui
   - ...etc
```

So you can have better management on classes.